# Putting a variable in an escaped string double quote

Tags: c#

Easy one, but annoying me :)

I am trying to subsitute a C# variable into a string that is already escaped and needs a double quote either side of the string for the WMI query to work.

Number one below works, this is where I hard code the string value

1.)

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searchObject = new        ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\MicrosoftBizTalkServer", "Select * from MSBTS_HostInstance where HostType=1 AND RunningServer = \"s2vm8\"", enumOptions);
```

Number two, I am trying to put in the C# variable but not sure how to do this in an already escaped string...

2.)

```
            ManagementObjectSearcher searchObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\MicrosoftBizTalkServer", "Select * from MSBTS_HostInstance where HostType=1 AND RunningServer = \"<c# variable>\"", enumOptions);
```

My string at the end for the WMI call needs to look like this:

```
 Select * from MSBTS_HostInstance where HostType=1 AND RunningServer = "blah..."
```

Thanks for your help!

Conor

Answer (score 4):

Preferable way of doing this:

```
String.Format("Select * from MSBTS_HostInstance where HostType=1 AND RunningServer = \"{0}\"", variable);
```

And another one:

```
"Select * from MSBTS_HostInstance where HostType=1 AND RunningServer = \"" + variable + "\""
```

Also, it is a good c# practice to replace

```
"root\\MicrosoftBizTalkServer"
```

with

```
@"root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply, I tried that but it doesnt work because ManagementObjectSearcher takes a specific number of arguments and I cant add one in my self with the {0}, or at least the complier wont let me :)

Comment: Perfect, knew it was easy, been too long since I coded with strings in C#!!